# Find out with JQuery if an input field in an iFrame gets selected by user

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe, user-input

iFrame HTML

[image: 1]

How can I find out with JQuery if a user selects the input field in the iFrame to trigger an event? Is there a way to iterate through the iFrame elements? iFrame is on same domain. If the user input field gets selected by user I would like to call an onscreen keyboard.

Comment: you can have code in the frame handle the "focus" event, and then call a function on `window.parent` or trigger an event there.

Comment: So you need to bind an event listener in the iframe. `yourIframe.contents()....`